# Create folder in command line using ansible (HDFS Storage)

Tags: ansible

I’m trying to create folder structure on HDFS storage. I have 3 main folders and each has subfolders.

I'm having a problem to update the subfolders - I'm expecting that the following commands will be executed

- hadoop fs -mkdir /ibm/it
- hadoop fs -mkdir /ibm/logistic
- hadoop fs -mkdir /hp
- hadoop fs -mkdir /dell/it
- hadoop fs -mkdir /dell/logistic

But instead, the following commands are executed (i used debug msg in order to print the command of the second task that is failed )
It looks that I need to run a loop on department that is a dictionary

```
ok: [10.201.51.16] => (item={u'department': [u'it', u'logistic'], u'company_folder_name': u'/ibm'}) => {
    "msg": "hadoop fs -mkdir /company//ibm/[u'it', u'logistic']"
}
ok: [10.201.51.16] => (item={u'department': None, u'company_folder_name': u'/hp'}) => {
    "msg": "hadoop fs -mkdir /company//hp/"
}
ok: [10.201.51.16] => (item={u'department': [u'it'], u'company_folder_name': u'/dell'}) => {
    "msg": "hadoop fs -mkdir /company//dell/[u'it']"
```

Thank you.

**Configuration file:**

```
companies:
     - company_folder_name: /ibm
       department:
            - it
            - logistic
     - company_folder_name: /hp
       department:
     - company_folder_name: /dell
       department:
            - it
```

**Playbook:**

```
## Createing the main folders - working fine ##
   - name: create company folders
     shell: hadoop fs -mkdir {{ item.company_folder_name }}
     register: result
     ignore_errors: yes
     with_items:
            - "{{ companies }}"

## Create subfolders - Not working ##
   - name: create department folders
     shell: hadoop fs -mkdir {{ item.company_folder_name }}/{{item.department}}
     register: result
     ignore_errors: yes
     with_items:
            - "{{ companies }}"
```

Comment: What is your exact problem ?

Comment: The output command of the second task should be like this:
1.hadoop fs -mkdir /ibm/it
2.hadoop fs -mkdir /ibm/logistic
3.hadoop fs -mkdir /hp
4.hadoop fs -mkdir /dell/it
5.hadoop fs -mkdir /dell/logistic

but what I’m getting is something different. I need to loop the department that is actually a dictionary.  (I used debug msg – in order to print the commands)

ok: [10.201.51.16] => (item={u'department': [u'it', u'logistic'], u'company_folder_name': u'/ibm'}) => {
    "msg": "hadoop fs -mkdir /company//ibm/[u'it', u'logistic']"

Comment: Please edit your question and add this info there.

Answer (score 0):

You had the firts part right with your first task for creating the company base directories.

For the next one, we first select in the list objects having a non-empty `departement` field. This is done below with the [`selectattr` filter](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#selectattr)

Then we loop on this list using the [`subelements` lookup](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup/subelements.html) so we get one iteration for each company/department combination.

The result playbook below:

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    companies:
      - company_folder_name: /ibm
        department:
          - it
          - logistic
      - company_folder_name: /hp
        department:
      - company_folder_name: /dell
        department:
          - it

  tasks:

    - name: create company folders
      debug:
        msg: "hadoop fs -mkdir {{ item.company_folder_name }}"
      with_items: "{{ companies }}"

    - name: create department folders
      debug:
        msg: "hadoop fs -mkdir {{ item.0.company_folder_name }}/{{ item.1 }}"
      with_subelements:
        - "{{ companies | selectattr('department') | list }}"
        - department
```

Which gives:

```
PLAY [localhost] ***************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [create company folders] **************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item={'company_folder_name': '/ibm', 'department': ['it', 'logistic']}) => {
    "msg": "hadoop fs -mkdir /ibm"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item={'company_folder_name': '/hp', 'department': None}) => {
    "msg": "hadoop fs -mkdir /hp"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item={'company_folder_name': '/dell', 'department': ['it']}) => {
    "msg": "hadoop fs -mkdir /dell"
}

TASK [create department folders] ***********************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=[{'company_folder_name': '/ibm'}, 'it']) => {
    "msg": "hadoop fs -mkdir /ibm/it"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=[{'company_folder_name': '/ibm'}, 'logistic']) => {
    "msg": "hadoop fs -mkdir /ibm/logistic"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=[{'company_folder_name': '/dell'}, 'it']) => {
    "msg": "hadoop fs -mkdir /dell/it"
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```